# ListView doesn't appear

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt

I'm working at app for ubuntu touch. I have a code with listView in it. But when I run it the page is simply empty (tehre is a title and a tabs switcher). Where is the mistake?

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import Ubuntu.Components.ListItems 0.1 as ListItem
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.0

MainView {

applicationName: "El Wohust"
objectName: "elwohust"

width: units.gu(50)
height: units.gu(75)
XmlListModel {
    id: portals
    source: "http://localhost/feed.xml"
    query: "/portals/item"

    XmlRole { name: "title"; query: "title/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "pubDate"; query: "pubDate/string()" }
 }

// Here

           Tab {
               title: i18n.tr("2nd list")
               Page {
                   id: subreddits
                   anchors.fill: parent

                   ListView {
                       id: articleList


                       model: portals
                       delegate: ListItem.Subtitled {
                                   text: title
                                   subText: pubDate
                                   progression: true
                                   onClicked: pageStack.push(articleView)
                               }

                   }
               }
}

}

}
```

Here is how the XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <portals>

    <item>
        <title>Karlův most</title>
        <pubDate>Sat, 07 Sep 2010 10:00:01 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Sv. Vít</title>
        <pubDate>Sat, 07 Sep 2010 15:35:01 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>

  </portals>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `anchors.fill: parent` on the ListView as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must do as the following for a ListView to work perfectly...

```
Column {
        spacing: units.gu(2)
        anchors.centerIn: parent.Center

        ListView {
            width: page.width
            height: page.height
            model: dictXMLList
            delegate: ListItem.Subtitled {
                text: word
                subText: meaning
                progression: true

            }

        }
```